# How save only time in Redshift HH:MM:SS

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, amazon-redshift

Importing table from MySql to RedShift, MySql have to columns which is `time` datatype

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| typecode        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slot_start_time | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slot_end_time   | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdon       | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modifiedon      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Redshift doesn't have time data type because of this after importing table `slot_start_time, slot_end_time` columns return `1970-01-01` in this case `slot_start_time, slot_end_time` show as `Date` datatype

When I `ALTER` both column in Redshift as timestamp then it will return '01/01/70 HH:MM'

So how I can save only time in RedShift.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly suggest against trying out such venture. You might end up using some non-compatible datatype, like *string* which might actually help you out just to store the time but would be ***catastrophic*** when you actually begin to query your data.

In worst case, Redshift might not even populate the date column if it finds the datatype not compatible and the entire column will be populated with null values.

In the Redshift table, store the entire timestamp in the format

> **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss** (use any placeholder date in the format; as date is irrelevant to you in any case)

and use any of the functions to extract only the timestamp while querying the table (an illustration is shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since you don't have time column in Redshift ,you can use the same date , for example '1970-01-01' and then to add the time.

then you will be able to run date_part on the field.

for example

```
select extract(hour from timestamp '2010-02-16 20:38:40');
date_part
```